# Como paso de un objeto a otro tipo de dato (Int, Double)

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, jdbc

Estoy haciendo un programa de facturacion en el cual el usuario ingresa los productos en una tabla

[image: ASI ES EL PROGRAMA]

pero cuando trato de guardar el registro a la base de datos me de un problema que segun dice intener es porque el objeto a pasar a Int o Double no son numeros

```
for (int o = 0; o<=jTable1.getRowCount(); o++) {
                                            System.out.println("bandera");
                                            String sql="INSERT INTO detalle_factura VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                                            PreparedStatement stmt; 
                                            stmt= objDatos.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                                            stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(o, 0).toString()));// cantidad
                                            stmt.setString(2,jTable1.getValueAt(o, 1).toString());// nombre producto
                                            stmt.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getValueAt(o, 2).toString()));//precio unitario
                                            stmt.setDouble(4, total);//total
                                            stmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(o, 4).toString()));//id producto
                                            stmt.setInt(6, coddet);// codigo factura    
                                            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();//while terminado falta verificacion
                                            if(i!=0){
                                            System.out.println("todo bien");
                                            }else{
                                                System.out.println("nel pastel");
                                            }
                                        }
```

ese es mi codigo y este es el error que se presenta en el LogCat:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at
> java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) at
> java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) at
> nopal.factura.jButton1ActionPerformed(factura.java:517) at
> nopal.factura.access$500(factura.java:30) at
> nopal.factura$5.actionPerformed(factura.java:276)

Comment: ¿En qué línea te marca el error? ¿El código de factura (`coddet`) es siempre numérico?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at nopal.factura.jButton1ActionPerformed(factura.java:517)
 at nopal.factura.access$500(factura.java:30)
 at nopal.factura$5.actionPerformed(factura.java:276)

Comment: es super largo el error pero este es el principio :(

Comment: coddet es un big decimal que lo recupero como auto generado, lo pongo en un jtexfield invisible y recupero el texto nada mas, si siempre es numerico

Comment: No es necesario copiar todo el error, sino la parte más relevante. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar el error exacto que te aparece. En el código que proporcionaste, ¿cuál es la línea 517? (que dice ser de `factura.java`)

Comment: el error te dice que estás pasando un string vacío y lo intentas convertir a número... valida tu información

Comment: stmt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(o, 4).toString().trim()));//id producto

Comment: ese es la linea 517, revisare los datos

Comment: mmm, me puedes mosntrar la tabla, es que normalmente el primer campo de las tablas en el ID, y tu lo estas poniendo en nulo, verifica que este eso bien, si me pasas tambien el catch podria ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

ok, ya me fije en los comentario de arriba tu error no tiene que ver nada con lo que dices, explicando un poco es problema es que intentas convertir una cadena vacía(`Integer.parseInt("")`) a numero y el programa de manda a decir que no puede convertir porque no hay nada(`""`)..
ahora te diré unas cosas que puedes intentar:

1. verifica los valores que cuando mandas a llamar a esa funcion los campos de la jtable tengan datos
2. verifica que la extraccion de los valores sea correcta con `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo es usar un método para validar el caso en el cual el valor no es númerico, en este caso puedes definir un valor default por ejemplo el `0` .

```
public static int convierteaInt(String numero, int defaultInt) {
    int resultado = defaultInt;
    try {
        if (numero != null) {
            resultado = Integer.parseInt(numero);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Este método lo usarías de esta forma, como ejemplo definiendo como valor default el 0.

```
stmt.setInt(5, convierteaInt(jTable1.getValueAt(o, 4).toString().trim()), 0);
```